# Android DatagramSocket not receiving after Back button pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, udp

In my application am doing a UDP broadcast over a local wifi network to discover a certain device. When the application does the initial broadcast I receive both the broadcast message (as expected) and then the response from the local device. Everything works great.

If I move forward to the next fragment (it is a device setup flow) and then press back and try to rediscover the local devices, I only receive the broadcast message and nothing else.

I have done some sniffing with Wireshark and can see the message going out on the network and can see the local device responding to the message. It seems that either the OS is dropping the packet or the application is somehow listening on the wrong port. I believe it could also have to do with the fragment being added to the backstack improperly.

I am looking for some suggestions or to see if any one has encountered a similar situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There was another thread that was accessing the same UDP socket and causing issues that I could not easily detect. I centralized all UDP communication and it worked like a charm!